# Database names from multiple SQL Servers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am stuck with a SQL query. How do I get all the databases names from multiple SQL Servers at a time? I have the server IP's in a table.

Comment: I dont think you'll be able to do that in one query. Your probably going to need a script or application to loop through each ip.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Please have a look, I have done it with a WHILE loop. Loop can be replaced with UNION if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives all the databases of the current server

```
EXEC sp_databases
```

If you know the other server ips you could use **sp_addlinkedserver** to link them and get the desired results.

**EDIT:** following is a complete answer for you as I described above but using sys.databases

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE (dbName VARCHAR(250),ipAddress VARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @SERVERS AS TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),serverIp VARCHAR(20),
                           rmUser VARCHAR(20),rmPassword VARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @ipAdd AS VARCHAR(20),@user AS VARCHAR(20), @pw AS VARCHAR(20),@rowCount AS INT

SELECT @rowCount = 1

--ADD THE LIST OF SERVERS WITH LOGIN USER NAME AND PASSWORDS HERE
INSERT INTO @SERVERS (serverIp,rmUser,rmPassword) 
    VALUES ('serverIp1','rmuser1','rmpassword1'), ('serverIp2','rmuser2','rmpassword2')

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT Id FROM @SERVERS WHERE Id = @rowCount)
BEGIN
SELECT @ipAdd = serverIp, @user= rmUser, @pw = rmPassword 
    FROM @SERVERS WHERE Id =  @rowCount

    --Link the server and add login
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @ipAdd,N'SQL Server';
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=@ipAdd, 
                          @useself='false',
                          @rmtuser=@user,
                          @rmtpassword=@pw

     --INSERT results into a temp view and then into @T
 EXEC('CREATE VIEW vTemp AS SELECT name FROM ['+@ipAdd+'].master.sys.databases')
 INSERT INTO @T  SELECT name,@ipAdd FROM vTemp

     --Drop view
 DROP VIEW vTemp

     --Drop login and link to the remort server
 EXEC sp_droplinkedsrvlogin @ipAdd, NULL
 EXEC sp_dropserver @ipAdd, NULL;

     SELECT @rowCount = @rowCount +1

END

--FINALLY YOUR RESULTS
SELECT * FROM @T
```

Comment: yes this is working. need to check with my superior if adding and removing linked server is ok with him... :)

Answer (score 4):

You can get the database informations using.

```
SELECT * from sys.databases
```

If you want to know this from other servers, in pure t-sql, you need to link the server.

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Linking Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)
- [MSDN - sp_addlinkedserver (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)

### Update after a comment

You say that you cant link the servers. Another alternative is to create a .NET CLR Object
and embed them to the server.

Than you can connect to other servers, without linking them together, and execute sql statements.

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Using CLR Integration in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345136%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: ok i even tried creating an SSIS package for this. even that doesn't have any option for changing the servers dynamically...And more over we need to run this in the production servers. so i should not link the servers.

Comment: @user920431 my answer is extended.